# how to call id from existing login session?

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("kudap", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];


// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select * from staff where NAMA='$user_check' ", $connection);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['NAMA'];

?>
```

actually i want id from staff table in database..  .. but i still dint know how to call the id...  using session..

Comment: `*` will fetch all column from staff table . so you have already fetched `Id` if there exists any in your `$row`

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension has been REMOVED from version 7 of PHP. You should now be using the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are fetching everything from the staff table. So, try using the following command. Hope it will work.

```
$login_id =$row['ID'];
```

Here, i guess the field name is "ID" in your staff table.

Comment: Then please mark the answer. It will help me too. Thanks

Comment: actually i has been use 3 files..  first 

1. loginscript.php
2. session.php
3. staff.php

1. in loginscript.php  i has been declare session ..... 
if($username==$calluser && $password== $callpass){
  $_SESSION['login_user']=$callnama; // one row
  $_SESSION['id_user']=$calluser; //one row

and in session.php i declare the session in other name  ...

$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$idp=$_SESSION['id_user'];